# SSD causes my Windows 7 installation to freeze

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, freeze

I have an ADATA S510 60GB SATA3 (AHCI mode) SSD, and an Asus M4A785TD-V EVO motherboard.

Quite often my computer freezes for about 30 seconds, and afterward returns to its normal state. I'm more than sure that this is caused by the SSD. Is there any way I can do something about this?

Comment: The best support would be to contact your manufacturer.

Comment: What makes you so sure that the SSD is the culprit?

Comment: Try updating the BIOS in the motherboard. Sometimes that will fix this problem on an Asus motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early/cheap SSDs have a tendency to pause or stutter.  Anandtech has had several articles mentioning [this](http://www.anandtech.com/print/2738).

If you want the more details about why this happens the term is [write amplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification)